# How to enable Two-Factor Authentication in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, command-line, two-factor-authentication

How do I enable it for all account types in Magento 2?

Anyone, please help me with how to enable the Two-factor Authentication module using a command line.

Comment: `bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth`
`bin/magento cache:flush`
it will disable that extension

Comment: See the post for your question - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/350529/3723

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this to disable using this command: `php bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/enable 0` if you want disable complete module than try this `php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth` and at the end `bin/magento cache:flush` also clear browser cookies or try incognito browser.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, check the module is disable or not by following command.

```
sudo bin/magento module:status
```

If, your module is not disable and you want to disable it, then deactivate it by following command.

```
sudo bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

clear cache.....

```
sudo bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope it work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

enable/disable:
`bin/magento module:enable/disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth --clear-static-content`  &&

`bin/magento setup:upgrade` && `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 1):

Try this module https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth. It disables it in developer mode and it easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable module using below command.

```
php bin/magento module:enable MSP_TwoFactorAuth
```

After module enable run below command.

If you have set the developer mode for you website then only run below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If you store set production mode then run below command.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope it work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If the mode is Developer you can run these commands:

```
sudo bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth;#Disable
#OR
sudo bin/magento module:enable Magento_TwoFactorAuth;#Enable
sudo php bin/magento c:c;
sudo rm -rf generated;
```

Answer (score -2):

Please run the below command in terminal:

```
bin/magento module:enable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

bin/magento cache:flush
```